# How to get a Sharepoint-group with its members displayed in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, groups, pnp-powershell

How to get a SharePoint-group with its members displayed in PowerShell. I have tried this:

```
Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" | select title
```

But doesn't give me the results I would like.

I use module PnP PowerShell and I use SharePoint online.

Answer (score 2):

The below PowerShell command retrieves all the SharePoint Groups from the SharePoint site and its users with users count for the group.

`Get-PnPGroup` PnP PowerShell cmdlet gets the SharePoint Groups from the SharePoint site collection.

```
PS:> $cred = Get-Credential  
PS:> Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/dev -Credential $cred  
PS:> $groups = Get-PnPGroup | Select-Object Title,Users  
PS:> $groups | format-table @{Expression = {$_.Title};Label='Group'},@{Expression = {$_.Users.Title};Label='Users'},@{Expression = {$_.Users.Count};Label='UsersCount'}
```

[image]

[Source](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-group-users-from-sharepoint-site-using-pnp-powershell)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Get-PnPGroupMembers` like below:

```
Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity 'Marketing Site Members'
```

Where `-Identity` is the title of the group.

Additionally you can also use `Get-PnPGroup` command like:

```
$group = Get-PnPGroup -Identity 'Marketing Site Members' -Includes Users
$group.Users
```

**Reference**:

1. [Get-PnPGroupMembers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpgroupmembers).
2. [Get-PnPGroup](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpgroup).
3. [Get Group Users From SharePoint Site Using PnP Powershell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/get-group-users-from-sharepoint-site-using-pnp-powershell).

Answer (score 0):

What resutls did you want get? This command `Get-PnPGroupMembers` will return all the users that are a member of the provided SharePoint Group.

If you want to get a SharePoint-group, you need to use command `Get-PnPGroup`. Like this:

```
Get-PnPGroupMembers -Identity "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

@Karthik Jaganathan's reply is very useful, you could refer to it to format the table.